# Test Observable in Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular2-services

I am developing an Angular based application where I need to do component communication. I am making use of service to achieve the desired working.

I am having hard time at testing the observable. Below are the code snippet for all the class:

TestComponent.ts file

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  id: number = -1;
  message: string;

  constructor(private testService: TestService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.testService.test1$
    .subscribe((id: number) => {
      this.id = id;
     });

    this.message= this.testService.getMessage();
  }
}
```

TestService.ts

```
export class TestService {

  onTestChange1 = new Subject<number>();

  onTestChange2 = new Subject<string>();

  // Observable string streams
  test1$ = this.onTestChange1.asObservable();
  test2$ = this.onTestChange2.asObservable();

  getTest1() {
    this.onTestChange1.next(1);
  }
  getTest2() {
    this.onTestChange2.next('Hi from 2');
  }

  getMessage(): string {
    return 'Hi';
  }
}
```

TestComponent Spec File:

```
fdescribe('TestComponent', () => {
  let component: TestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

  let test: TestMockService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    test = new TestMockService();
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TestComponent ],
      providers: [
        {provide: TestService, useValue: test}
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should message to be true Hi', async(() => {

    const dataStub = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(TestService);
    const spy = spyOn(dataStub, 'getMessage').and.returnValue('Hi');

    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(component.message1).toBe('Hi');
    });
  }));

  it('id should be equal to 1', async(() => {
    const dataStub = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(TestService);
    const spy = spyOn(dataStub, 'getTest1').and.returnValue(Observable.of(1));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component.id).toBe(1);
    });
  }));

});
```

The last test where the 'id' is under test is failing and I am not sure why!

I know I am missing something really small and important which is why my code is not working. It would be really great if anyone can help me understand and correct my code.

A prompt response would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: maybe use  new BehaviorSubject() instead of subject?

Comment: It did not work with BehaviorSubject, may be I am going wrong somewhere else.

Comment: There are several problems with your test. 1. we have no idea what TestMockService is. 2. you spy on getTest1, but the component never calls that method. 3. Even if it did call getTest1(), you spy *after* the component has been created and ngOnInited, so the real method has already been called by the component at that time.

Comment: I am making use of the injected Service from the component to make the call. I believe when you make spy it directly gets called when you call fixture.detectChanges() method. Please do correct me if I am wrong here.                                                                                                                 I have used the similar process for testing the 'getMessage' method in the component. It worked for me there but its not working in the Observable case.